# Pass in argument to Tomcat Servlet

Tags: tomcat, web-config, tomcat7, config

I'm building a Web servlet using tomcat 7 that, as part of what it does, accesses a RESTful API. Currently, that URL is hard coded in as a string in my servlet, but I want to move it out so that once the servlet is finished, I could pass in the URL that servlet should be connecting to instead of having it hard coded in. What's the best way to do this? I've read that I should add a context.xml file in the META-INF folder, but wouldn't this mean that I need to repackage the war if I want to change the URL of the API?

Comment: You can put it in an init parameter in the web.xml. If your concern is that you want to change the parameter without repackaging the application then read a properties file from somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Use an init-param to exteralize the configuration of the servlet to the standard web.xml file:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>My servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.foo.bar.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param> 
        <description>Restful API URL</description> 
        <param-name>restfulApiUrl</param-name> 
        <param-value>http://www.foo.com/api/</param-value> 
    </init-param> 
</servlet>
```

And access it from your servlet initialization method:

```
private String restulApiUrl;

@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    restulApiUrl = config.getInitParameter("restfulApiUrl");
}
```

This will indeed force you to repackage the war when you change the value, unless youd deploy the app as an exploded war.

You can of course imagine meny other solutions: use a system property (passed when Tomcat is started), store it in a file read at startup time, store it in the database, etc.

Comment: This doesn't address the OPs concern with the need to repackage the application if this changes.

Comment: I added a note about that at the end.